# Clearing the bash "source buffer"

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, buffer

When running a bash script like `source script` or `. script` from the command line, then all the lines in the script are added to bash's "source buffer" and then the current command shell just continues. Stopping execution is impossible (apart from aborting the shell), using ctrl-C only interrupts the current command, but then the next command is executed.

Where is this buffer, and would it be possible to clear it??

Example script:

```
echo A
sleep 10
echo B
sleep 10
echo C
sleep 10
echo D
```

After having done "source script", is there any way to stop it executing any further after it has been 'submitted'?

Comment: Please add your script to your question.

Comment: Why are you using `source`?  If you have these issues then you probably should run it as a separate process.

Comment: Using source because of the convenience being able to use the variables in the shell if needed after the script finishes running.

It's not that I have issues, I'm just curious about this. I know that whenever a return statement occurs, the rest of the buffer gets discarded, but what if you've sourced a script like the one above, and you want to stop it while staying in the same shell (preserving the current environment and variables).

Answer (score 0):

There is - to the best of my knowledge - no such thing as a *source buffer* in bash, so there is nothing to erase. The `source` command just executes the commands found in its arguments in the current environment (i.e. not in a child process).

There is nothing in the handling of `source` which is in particular related to the handling of signals. Maybe your shell script  is setup to ignore Control-C? I suggest that you run your script with -x in order to find the culprit.

Comment: I think the official name (according to the bash man page) is the call stack or the execution call stack (grep the bash man page for 'call stack'). When "sourcing" a script (grep the bash man page for 'source'), the commands in it get read and executed in the current shell.

I tried adding a line "chmod -r script" in the middle of the script, but that didn't stop the execution, so I think the commands get read into a buffer and then executed.

Comment: It is correct, that a call stack is used for, for instance, invoking a shell function, and sourcing a script. However, this is an implementation detail and has nothing to do with your problem of not being able to cancel an invocation. You can easily verify this by setting up two file: `sub.sh`, which contains the line `echo x; sleep 600;echo y`, and `main.sh`, which contains the line `source sub.sh; echo z`. If you invoke this by `bash main.sh`, you will see that it outputs *x* and then sleeps. If you abort it with Control-C at this point, it will immediately terminate, no further output.

Comment: But that is because you put all the commands in sub.sh on the same line with semicolons. If you put each on a separate line, it will print y and z. But it's interesting... If you put the sleep 600 on the same line as echo x it does stop, same as when you put sleep 600; echo y

I wonder if this is actually supposed to happen like this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the lines. I put them on the same line, because I see no way in the *Comment* function of StackOverflow to write code in several lines. Feel free to replace all the semicolons by newlines.

Comment: If I put them on separate lines, it doesn't terminate, it will also echo y and z.

Comment: It does. I just tried exactly this example. See the screenshot [here](http://pasteboard.co/7GXoDBTag.jpg). If the signal is not delivered, it means that either there is a trap set up for the signal, or that Control-C does not deliver the signal. You can check the former by inserting the command `trap -p` in the beginning of your sub.sh, which would list all traps being present. For the latter, do a `stty -a` and verify that the output of this command contains *intr = ^C*.

Comment: It looks like if you source it, it will continue, but if you run bash, it's a subshell. See [this screenshot](http://pasteboard.co/8aD5Pgc1O.png)

Comment: Ah, well,  if you run *source* from the command line, things are different. In this case, the current shell - i.e. the one running your command line - receives the interrupt, and of course it must trap it (otherwise your command line would terminate). This is why I said that there is probably some process trapping your signal. The man page says about an interactive bash: *SIGINT is caught and handled (so that the wait builtin is interruptible)*. While it doesn't say so explicitly, I guess this means that except of the `wait` case, it doesn't do anything special with SIGINT.

Comment: I edited the question clarifying that it's about an interactive shell.

I was then wondering why setting a trap to 'return' doesn't work...

Comment: @PePa: To answer this, please show how exactly you set up the trap. BTW, I understand that you are using `source`, because you are wanting to set variables in your shell. I don't know the exact requirements of your application, but if this process takes so long that you want to interrupt it, it would be worth considering a redesign of the whole process.

Comment: I tried the line "trap return INT" first in main.sh and then in sub.sh
At this point, it is just curiosity about the initial question. I went with a design where the main file is sourced, and setting the important variables that I want to be able to access in the interactive shell, and then executing scripts from there. Because I want to distribute it in a single file, I am writing the executable scripts from within the main sourced file and then setting them executable before calling them.

Comment: For what you want to achieve (distribute in a single file), wouldn't be a shell archive the better solution? See the *shar* man page. As for you attempt to trap SIGINT, my feeling is that the *return* would just cause control being handed back to the interrupted side, hence in effect "ignoring" the signal.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about shar, I've never used it.

Comment: Neither did I, but I think in your case it could do the job  ;-)